# PrintWriter in java giving unexpected behaviour

Tags: java, io, printwriter

```
import java.io.*;
class demo
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(System.out);
    pw.println("java");
    //pw.print("java");
}
}
```

// the output is `java` using `pw.println` but output is null using `pw.print` i.e nothing gets printed on console while using `print`.

Comment: Are you sure this is not just your shell "hiding" it from you, since the program does not echo a newline? You could try piping the output to a file to check whether this happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(System.out);
pw.print("java");
pw.flush();
```

The `PrintWriter` is going to be doing internal buffering, and the `println` method is automatically flushing it.

Comment: but why the following code don't work:                     PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(System.out,true);
pw.print("java");

Comment: If you look at the javadoc (http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) you'll see that "if automatic flushing is enabled it will be done only when one of the println() methods is invoked, rather than whenever a newline character happens to be output."

So, the only way to make it do what you want it to do is to actually call `flush()`

Answer (score 6):

It's almost certainly just buffering - and as you're not flushing it, you never get the output. From [the docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html):

> Unlike the PrintStream class, if automatic flushing is enabled it will be done only when one of the println, printf, or format methods is invoked, rather than whenever a newline character happens to be output. These methods use the platform's own notion of line separator rather than the newline character.

Try:

```
pw.flush();
```

at the end of the code.

Answer (score 1):

For automatic flushing, you could use this constructor

```
PrintWriter(OutputStream out, boolean autoFlush);
```

Comment: Did you put autoFlush to true?

Comment: ya i tried this: PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(System.out,true); pw.print("java"); but no solutions

Answer (score 0):

A call to `println()` implicitly flushes the output buffer whereas a call to `print()` does not.  Try using `print()` and then call `pw.flush()`.

Note also that there are constructors of PrintWriter which include an option to automatically flush after any write call.